# Can window.onload fire when new image().src hasn't yet been loaded?

Tags: javascript, onload

Does `window.onload` take into account loading of `new image().src` elsewhere in a script?

My issue rises from procedurally generating several image assets, and I seem unable to get each `image.length` until a few moments after.

Comment: Try adding $(document).ready(function(){ ...//your code ... });

Comment: @Ali - that won't work without jQuery

Comment: Yeah, I'm making a point out of not using JQuery. Should I write my own pre-loader that keeps track of everything that has to be loaded before I query the .length?